# Request to create the arduino-create tag

Tags: feature-request, tags

I've never requested a new tag before.

I have [a question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/60033/42469) about the [Arduino Create site](https://create.arduino.cc/editor) but there's no tag for it yet.

It would be great if a tag like `arduino-create` or `create` could be made for questions about the site and how to use it.

Comment: done............